# jQuery wrap from one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of struggle while trying to wrap some unwrapped content within a div. The code looks like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="A1">some content</div>
 <div class="A2">some content</div>
 Unwrapped text
 <div class="A3">some content</div>

 <div class="B1">some content</div>
 <div class="B2">some content</div>
 Unwrapped text
 <div class="B3">some content</div>
</div>
```

As you see, what i want to do is to wrap all A-elements into one div, and also include the unwrapped text in between. And then, do the same with the B-elements. Any ideas?

Comment: @j08691 Haven't tried anything more than using .before() -method & .append() to add opening and closing divs at certain points, but these also automatically add closing tags which makes it impossible.

Comment: *"And then. do the same with the B-elements"*, soooo, you want to wrap the unwrapped text twice, or how is that supposed to work ?

Comment: Is the code you posted the sole condition or could the number and position of elements change?

Comment: What does the expected output look like?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated to wrap textnodes inbetween elements, so the first thing to do, is wrap those textnodes with spans

```
var wrap = $('.wrap'),
    html = wrap.contents();

html.filter(function(i, el) {
    if (el.nodeType === 3 && el.nodeValue && el.nodeValue.trim().length) 
       $(el).wrap('<span class="wrapped_in" />');
});
```

Then it's just a matter of iterating over the children in reverse, and wrapping them up

```
wrap.children().toArray().reverse().forEach(function(elem) {
    if ( $(elem).closest('.wrapped').length > 0 || $(elem).hasClass('wrapped_in') ) 
        return false;

    var char = (elem.className || "_").charAt(0);

    var elem = $('[class^="'+char+'"]');
    $(elem.add(elem.prev('.wrapped_in'))).wrapAll('<div class="wrapped wrap_'+(++i)+'" />')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/gLaqotp0/)

If for some reason you don't want the textnodes wrapped in spans, just unwrap them after all the other wrapping is done

```
$('.wrapped_in').contents().unwrap()
```

Comment: why did you use reverse?

Comment: obviously. I mean why did you want to iterate in reverse and not keep the array as it is. And I just removed the reverse part in testing and it looks like it didn't make a difference(it's still properly wrapped). Thanks for your code.

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```js
var split = function() {
  var arr = ['A', 'B'];
  for (var i in arr) {
    var ch = arr[i];
    $("<div class='" + ch + "'>").insertBefore("div[class*='" + ch + "']:first");
    $("<div class='" + ch + "'>").insertAfter("div[class*='" + ch + "']:last");
  }
}
```

```css
.A,
.B {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="A1">some content</div>
  <div class="A2">some content</div>
  Unwrapped text
  <div class="A3">some content</div>

  <div class="B1">some content</div>
  <div class="B2">some content</div>
  Unwrapped text
  <div class="B3">some content</div>
</div>
<button onclick="split()">Split Divs</button>
```

Comment: yup, this could be a better solution to group and wrap.. Regards.. +1

Comment: Thanks for the code, however though, your code shows a perfect example of elements where there's a pattern (A or B). I used those references just to explain a little bit easier what i was trying to achieve. My struggle is that i have no such pattern, the classes are completely different, in no logical structure. Do you have a pattern like e.g. for each 5 nodes of parent-div (.wrap), write opening div on first and closing on last?

Comment: Nope, this inserts empty divs before and after the class groups, it's not actually wrapping them.

Comment: @CodedropTeam You should update your question to clarify that. Also provide the expected output....